# Multiple clicks required to complete two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have some javascript that for some reason requires two consecutive clicks in order to function correctly.  Here is the code for the link:

```
<a href="" onclick="select_all_com(); return false">Select All</a>
```

Now, here is the code for the function that is called with the onclick:

```
function select_all_com(){
$("[name=file_com_appeal].com-checkbox").each( function() {   
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
}); 
UpdateTotalFee();
}
```

and finally, here is the last bit of code:

```
function UpdateTotalFee(){
    var AppealCount = 0;

    $('input[name=file_com_appeal].com-checkbox').each(function(){
    if( $(this).next().hasClass('checked') ){ 
        AppealCount++; } 
    });

    $('#AppealFeeTotal').text("$"+(AppealCount*140));
}
```

This final part is supposed to run the first time the link is clicked but some reason it does not run the first time, only the second time.  Specifically what I mean is that the first click updates all of the checkboxes from off to on, but does not update the `#AppealFeeTotal`.  A subsequent click of the Select All link when the checkboxes are already selected then causes the `#AppealFeeTotal` to update.

Any ideas why this might be requiring two clicks?  I should also add that there is one line of code in particular that I am unsure about.  I inherited the code from someone else, and I'm not sure of the reason why this is used:

```
if( $(this).next().hasClass('checked') ){
```

Thanks for any ideas you might have.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Hi Felix, I would like to create a jsfiddle demo, but I'm afraid it is proving to be too complicated for me.

Comment: @DanielAttard my solution is working? it is pure jQuery but i think it will work!

Comment: Mmmh, ok then. I still recommend you to get familiar with it, for the future. It makes it a lot easier for us to help you and you increase the chances of getting helpful answers.

Comment: `$(this).attr('checked', true);` should use `$(this).prop('checked', true);` See `attr()` docs. **if jQuery version >=1.6**

Comment: @AspiringAqib  in all browsers? There are good resons that the `prop()` method was created... and `checked` is a property not attribute. In older versions `attr()` was only choice but better habit to use correct one

Comment: @charlietfl ok man, but can you review my code as you have much knowledge? i think there will be a mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things, first `attr('checked')` is not the same as `hasClass('checked')` I suspect this is where your problem is. Your code does not add a "checked" class that I can see, but you're counting where that is the case. You should be using `is:checked` selector for this.

Second, if I read your code correctly, you're just counting checked checkboxes to get your total. You can do this more efficiently like this:

`$(":checkbox").filter(':checked').length`

Naturally you'll want to refine that selector (so it only counts specific checkboxes) but without more html, I can't help with that.

Comment: thanks @M_M.  This comment got me on the right track to solving my problem.  It turns out my references were not correct.  I was not paying attention to the difference between attr('checked') and hasClass('checked').  Once I was referring to the correct attribute, everything fell into place.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function() { // this is a function which execute when document is ready in jQuery
var clicks = 0; // I am taking clicks variable so, to check whether the user have clicked for the first time

$("a").on("click", function() { // this is a function which execute when target anchor tag is clicked
    clicks++; // now user have clicked the anchor tag so, i have to increase value to 1
    if(clicks==1) { // this condition checks whether user have clicked the anchor tag for the first time? if yes, then execute the code
        $("[name=file_com_appeal].com-checkbox").each( function() { // this is a each function which loops through all targets perform operations
        $(this).attr('checked', true); // while looping through all targets this will set attribute or property "checked" to true means its checked
        });
    }
    else if(clicks==2) { // this conditions check that whether anchor tag is clicked for second time
        var AppealCount = 0;
        $('input[name=file_com_appeal].com-checkbox').each(function(){
            if( $(this).prop('checked') ){ 
                AppealCount++; 
            } 
        });
        $('#AppealFeeTotal').text("$"+(AppealCount*140));
        clicks = 0; // set to zero because if user repeatedly clicks the anchor tag
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Should I put this in a separate function?  Where does it go?

Comment: buddy you just have to copy and paste in your script tag and also give anchor tag a unique id to properly work! and remove all onclick functions from anchor tag this is a full code ;)

Comment: Just code without any explanation is not really helpful! Please explain what you changed compared to the original code, why the original code did not work and why yours should solve the problem.

Comment: My question at this point is whether I have to remove the existing onclick function in my link in order to use this solution. . . . just noticed your comment now that I should remove all onclick functions from the anchor tag.  I will try this now and let you know how I make out.

Comment: yes and also your functions e.g. UpdateTotalFee() but keep backup if this do not worked but i think it will ;)

Comment: @FelixKling is this ok now? or should i add more explanatory comments?

Comment: Thanks @Aspiring Aqib for all your comments, ...and your patience.    Your code worked for me, but it turned out that my problem was related to the fact that I was not paying attention to the difference between attr('checked') and hasClass('checked').  Once my references were fixed, all worked perfectly.  Thanks again.